# Solving diag$(x_1,\dots,x_n) (Ax - b) = 0 $ without doing $2^n$ separate Gaussian Eliminations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $F$ be a field. I am interested in solving equations of the form
$$\text{diag}(x_1,\dots,x_n) (Ax - b) = 0 $$
for $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in F^n$ where $A$ is a $n \times n$-matrix over $F$ and $b \in F^n$ .

For any $J \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ we can consider the matrix $A_J$ by taking only the rows and colums of $A$ corresponding to indices contained in $J$.
Let $$L_J = \{x \:|\: A_J x_J = b_J \text{ and } x_i = 0 \text{ if } i \not\in J \}$$
where $x_J$ and $b_J$ are defined analogously to $A_J$.
Then the set of solutions $L$ of the above equation satisfies $L = \bigcup_J L_J$.
Thus, $L$ can be determined by computing $L_J$ for every $J \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Is there a better way to do this than to calculate the $2^n$ sets $L_J$ separately?

---

**Motivation**:

If I want to know the extreme values of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$    in the first quadrant this is the same as looking for extrema of $g(x) = f(x_1^2,\dots,x_n^2)$ and the gradient of $g$ is the product of $2 \text{ diag}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and the gradient of $f$. If $f$ is of the form $f(x) = x^T B x + x^T b $ you essentially end up looking for solutions of equations of the sort described above.

Comment: @Matthias I'm not sure, but here's a potentially helpful way to frame the problem. Let $a_{ij}$ denote the entries of $A$. For $n = 3$, $L_{\{1\}}$ is the solution set to the system
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1} x = \pmatrix{b_1\\0\\0}
$$
and $L_{\{1,3\}}$ is the solution set to 
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
0&1&0\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}} x = \pmatrix{b_1\\0\\b_3}.
$$
I hope the general pattern is clear.

Comment: @Matthias And of course these are equivalent to the arguably simpler
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} & 0 & 0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1} x = \pmatrix{b_1\\0\\0}, \quad 
\pmatrix{a_{11} & 0 & a_{13}\\ 0&1&0\\ a_{31} & 0 & a_{33}} x = \pmatrix{b_1\\0\\b_3}.
$$

Comment: Also, a potentially helpful observation: if either $F$ is sufficiently large, the "most probable" outcome is that each $L_J$ contains a single element. I suspect that the same generally is true for large $n$, but it's not so clear that this would occur in the case that $F = \Bbb F_2$ since the number of equations grows as quickly as the space $F^n$ of possible solutions.